# How do I access one function's content in an IIFE?

Tags: javascript

I have written some javascript code using the IIFE, here I have stored a variable `x` in a function `item1` inside the IIFE `hidden`. Now I want to create another function, say `item2` and I want to use the variable `x` inside this new function. And how exactly do I do this?

```js
var hidden = (function () {
  var item1 = function () {
    x = 5;
  }
})();
```

Comment: you don't...... (well maybe since x is global...)

Comment: How is item1 called?

Comment: You can expose the variable `x` by using the `revealing module pattern`

Comment: I forgot to mention about the calling mechanism. Well I use eventhandler to call the function

Comment: The function IIFE has a different scope you don't have the access to that variable

Outer function's variable don't have access to inner function's variable

Comment: @VinceSanchezTañan what does that mean ?

Comment: There are multiple issues here--`x` is global so it'd be accessible anywhere but since `item1` is never invoked inside of `hidden` the code that defines `x` can never execute. So what you're asking is impossible given the current code.

Comment: The global x seems to defeat the point of using IIFE, there is no return so hidden is undefined .... what is the point of the IIFE in first place? Example is really a bit too trivial for constructive discussion

Comment: @charlietfl, well I just use that code to make it a bit simpler and I am very new to JavaScript and to IIFE as well. I am confused about the return and I have no idea how the return works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` can be a variable in your iife so it acts like a private variable while you only expose the closures `item1` and `item2`.

Below is a simple example:

```
var hidden = (function(){
      var x;
      var item1 = function(){
              x=5;
       }
      var item2 = function(){
              return x;
       }

      return {
            item1: item1,
            item2: item2
      }
 })();
 hidden.item1()
 console.log("value of x", hidden.item2())
```

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit? I mean, in the item1 function, 5 is stored in x but it should be impossible to return x at item2 function, right? Because X=5 is exclusive to item1 function only

Comment: When you declare a variable (`x` in this case) within a function it can accessed anywhere in the scope of the function. Since `item1` and `item2` are also within the scope of iife they can access `x`. If `x` was declared inside `item1` then it would not have been possible for `item2` to access it.